# Find all solutions to the equation functional $f(x)+f(x+y)=y+2$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all solutions to the equation functional $f(x)+f(x+y)=y+2$

Letting $y=0$ one gets $2f(x) = 2 \Rightarrow f(x) = 1.$

I found this problem on aops and the proposed solution made the same observation and then stated

"Substituting this into the given functional equation yields $2=y+2$, which is not true for all $y$. Thus the given functional equation has no solutions."

However I don't see how they made the conclusion? Substituting this back gets

$1+f(x+y)=y+2$? If I would keep $y=0$ I would get $1+f(x) = 1+1 = 2$? What am I missing here?

Comment: The first step shows that $f(x)=1$ for all $x$, i.e. that $f$ is constant equal to $1$. In particular, in the second step, you have $f(x)=1$ **and** $f(x+y)=1$.

Comment: You need to substitute $f(x)$ in whole equation to see the problem, you get $f(x)=1$, $f(x+y)=1$ and hence $1+1=y+2$, for ALL $y$, so particualrly for example for $y=1$ we would get $0\neq 1$, absurd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are trying to find functions ${f}$ that satisfy

$${f(x) + f(x+y) = y + 2}$$

for all ${x,y \in \mathbb{R}}$. Setting ${y=0}$ (which we are completely allowed to do as it should hold for any ${x,y \in \mathbb{R}}$) shows us, as you pointed out, that

$${f(x) = 1\ \forall\ x \in \mathbb{R}}$$

In particular, we will also then have that

$${f(x+y)=1\ \forall\ x,y \in \mathbb{R}}$$

So, you see that

$${f(x)+f(x+y)=y+2}$$

would imply that

$${1+1=y+2\Leftrightarrow 2=y+2}$$

... but there is an obvious problem with this. This equation is only satisfied for ${y=0}$, hence there is no function $f$ such that ${\forall\ x,y \in \mathbb{R}}$ we have

$${f(x)+f(x+y)=y+2}$$

It's not possible.